# How to make an input form in Java code (not Netbeans using JForm)?

Tags: java, forms, swing

I want to make an input form in Java so that the user can enter details.

Something like this:

[image: desired form]

---

### My code

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

class JOptionPaneTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] items = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"};
    JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(items);
    JTextField field1 = new JTextField("1234.56");
    JTextField field2 = new JTextField("9876.54");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    panel.add(combo);
    panel.add(new JLabel("Field 1:"));
    panel.add(field1);
    panel.add(new JLabel("Field 2:"));
    panel.add(field2);
   int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel, "Test",
        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
        System.out.println(combo.getSelectedItem()
            + " " + field1.getText()
            + " " + field2.getText());
    } else {
        System.out.println("Cancelled");
    }
}
}
```

---

My output form:

[image: current state of form]

I think I must change my layout to something like `BorderLayout`. Any ideas how to get the look of the form at the top of the question?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you have to change layout. Have a look at [SpringLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html) and this example:

[image]
<sub>(source: [sun.com](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/figures/uiswing/layout/SpringForm.png))</sub>

```
String[] labels = {"Name: ", "Fax: ", "Email: ", "Address: "};
int numPairs = labels.length;

//Create and populate the panel.
JPanel p = new JPanel(new SpringLayout());
for (int i = 0; i < numPairs; i++) {
    JLabel l = new JLabel(labels[i], JLabel.TRAILING);
    p.add(l);
    JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
    l.setLabelFor(textField);
    p.add(textField);
}

//Lay out the panel.
SpringUtilities.makeCompactGrid(p,
                                numPairs, 2, //rows, cols
                                6, 6,        //initX, initY
                                6, 6);       //xPad, yPad
```

SpringLayout works fine for this simple form, but there is third party libraries that has more features. I.e. [MiG Layout](http://www.miglayout.com/).

Answer (score 10):

Another way to create a form using [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html), producing the following result:

[image]

Code:

```
JPanel addressPanel = new JPanel();
Border border = addressPanel.getBorder();
Border margin = new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10);
addressPanel.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(border, margin));

GridBagLayout panelGridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
panelGridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[] { 86, 86, 0 };
panelGridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[] { 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 0 };
panelGridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };
panelGridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                               Double.MIN_VALUE };
addressPanel.setLayout(panelGridBagLayout);

addLabelAndTextField("City:", 0, addressPanel);
addLabelAndTextField("Street:", 1, addressPanel);
addLabelAndTextField("State:", 2, addressPanel);
addLabelAndTextField("Phone:", 3, addressPanel);
addLabelAndTextField("Mail:", 4, addressPanel);
```

The helper method `addLabelAndTextField`:

```
private void addLabelAndTextField(String labelText, int yPos,
                                  Container containingPanel) {

    JLabel label = new JLabel(labelText);
    GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraintForLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraintForLabel.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gridBagConstraintForLabel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gridBagConstraintForLabel.gridx = 0;
    gridBagConstraintForLabel.gridy = yPos;
    containingPanel.add(label, gridBagConstraintForLabel);

    JTextField textField = new JTextField();
    GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraintForTextField = new GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraintForTextField.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gridBagConstraintForTextField.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gridBagConstraintForTextField.gridx = 1;
    gridBagConstraintForTextField.gridy = yPos;
    containingPanel.add(textField, gridBagConstraintForTextField);
    textField.setColumns(10);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are currently using a GridLayout, which can be fine for your need.

However, you should initialize it with the actual number of rows and columns you will need. In your case:

```
new GridLayout(0, 2);
```

0 for rows means there is not limit, and you have 2 columns, one for the labels, and one for the input component. See the [Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) for more information on GridLayouts.

[image]
<sub>(source: [sun.com](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/figures/uiswing/layout/GridLayoutDemo.png))</sub>

Note however that the GridLayout will make all "cells" to be the same size, which can be a problem for the labels.

However, Jonas is right, a [SpringLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html) is probably more adapted to your need.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with [DesignGridLayout](https://designgridlayout.dev.java.net/). The following snippet should work (sorry I could not test it I am not on my dev station right now):

```
DesignGridLayout layout = new DesignGridLayout(panel);
layout.row().grid(streetAddressLabel).add(streetAddressField);
layout.row().grid(cityLabel).add(cityField);
layout.row().grid(stateLabel).add(stateSpinner);
layout.row().grid(zipLabel).add(zipField);
layout.emptyRow();
layout.row().right().add(setAddressButton, clearAddressButton);
```

Then you would use `JDialog` (rather than `JOptionPane`) to display your `panel`.